# Tap on SwiftUI LocationButton in UI Test

Tags: swift, xctest

I am unable to tap on the `LocationButton` in a Swift UI Test. This is the button:

[image]

I am in a breakpoint in a UITest and I tried this without luck:

- `app.buttons.count` returns 0
- `app.staticTexts["Current Location"].exists` returns `false`
- `app.buttons["Current Location"].exists` returns `false`

Is there something special about this button? How can I tap it in a UITest?

Comment: Did you try with an accessibility identifier?

Answer (score 0):

```
 VStack {
            LocationButton(.shareCurrentLocation) {
                locationManager.requestLocation()
            }
            .cornerRadius(30)
            .symbolVariant(.fill)
            .foregroundColor(.white)
        }
        .accessibilityIdentifier("buttonStack")




  let button = app.otherElements["buttonStack"]
```

Found workaround with this way but not pretty.